# Android Display a DialogFragment when an option is clicked in a NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, navigation-drawer, android-dialogfragment

I need to display a DialogFragment when the "logout" option is selected inside a NavigationDrawer. Currently, I have implemented the following code but it does not work. Please, if someone know how to do it, tell me.

The implicated case in the switch is the third.

I have the following code:

In **MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity**

```
@Override
    public void onNavigationDrawerItemSelected(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        FragmentManager fragmentManager = getSupportFragmentManager();

        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                LinearLayout tecladoLayout = new LinearLayout(MainActivity.this);
                tecladoLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
                tecladoLayout.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT));
                tecladoLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

                String nombreMesa = ListaElectoresHolder.getInstance().getMesaAlias() == null ? ListaElectoresHolder.getInstance().getMesaId() : ListaElectoresHolder.getInstance().getMesaAlias();


                TextView textViewTeclado = new TextView(MainActivity.this);
                textViewTeclado.setTextSize(18);
                textViewTeclado.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                textViewTeclado.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
                textViewTeclado.setText(getString(R.string.etiqueta_mesa_asignada) + " " + nombreMesa);

                tecladoLayout.addView(textViewTeclado);
                getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(tecladoLayout);
                fragment = new TecladoFragment();
                break;
            case 1:
                getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_aciion_bar_censo);
                fragment = new Listado();
                break;
            case 2:
                getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.custom_action_bar_mesa);
                fragment = new Contacto();
                break;
            case 3:
                ManageSharedPreferences manageSharedPreferences = new ManageSharedPreferences(this);
                DatabaseHelper databaseHelper = new DatabaseHelper(this);
                if (true) {
                    showCancelVoteDialog(manageSharedPreferences, fragmentManager);
                } else {
                    manageSharedPreferences.removeAuthenticationData();
                    AppConstants.goToActivity(this, LoginActivity.class);
                }

                break;
        }
        fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.container, fragment)
                .commit();
    }
```

**And the showCancelDialog method:**

```
private void showCancelVoteDialog(final ManageSharedPreferences manageSharedPreferences, FragmentManager fragmentManager) {
        String message = this.getString(R.string.warning_not_empty_pile);
        CancelVoteDialogFragment cancelVoteDialogFragment = CancelVoteDialogFragment.newInstance(new CancelVoteDialogFragment.CancelVoteDialogListener() {
            @Override
            public void onOkButtonClick() {
                manageSharedPreferences.removeAuthenticationData();
                AppConstants.goToActivity(thisActivity, LoginActivity.class);
                thisActivity.finish();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelButtonClick() {
                // No hace nada
            }
        }, String.valueOf(message));
        cancelVoteDialogFragment.show(fragmentManager, getString(R.string.not_empty_pile_dialog));
    }
```

**Finally, the custom DialogFragment:**

```
public class CancelVoteDialogFragment extends DialogFragment {

    private static CancelVoteDialogListener cancelVoteDialogListener;
    private Typeface cabinRegular;


    public interface CancelVoteDialogListener {
        public void onOkButtonClick();

        public void onCancelButtonClick();
    }

    public static CancelVoteDialogFragment newInstance(CancelVoteDialogListener cancelVoteDialogListener, String message) {
        CancelVoteDialogFragment cancelVoteDialogFragment = new CancelVoteDialogFragment();
        CancelVoteDialogFragment.cancelVoteDialogListener = cancelVoteDialogListener;
        Bundle arguments = new Bundle();
        arguments.putString(AppConstants.BODYDIALOGMESSAGE, message);
        cancelVoteDialogFragment.setArguments(arguments);
        return cancelVoteDialogFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        // Elimina el título
        getDialog().getWindow().requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);

        // Obtiene los botones de acción
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cancel_vote_dialog, container, false);
        RelativeLayout okButton = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnAceptVoteDialog);
        RelativeLayout cancelButton = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCancelVoteDialog);
        TextView textViewMessage = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblMessageWarningCancelVote);
        TextView lblTitleDialog = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.lblTitleCancelVote);
        cabinRegular = Typeface.createFromAsset(this.getActivity().getAssets(), "fonts/Cabin-Regular.ttf");
        String message = getArguments().getString(AppConstants.BODYDIALOGMESSAGE);
        textViewMessage.setText(message);
        textViewMessage.setTypeface(cabinRegular);
        lblTitleDialog.setTypeface(cabinRegular);


        // Listeners
        okButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancelVoteDialogListener.onOkButtonClick();
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        cancelButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                cancelVoteDialogListener.onCancelButtonClick();
                dismiss();
            }
        });
        return view;
    }
}
```

Thanks!!!!

Comment: Where's the logout button and what dialog you want to call? Your code looks so messy.

Comment: The logout button is in the navigationDrawer, when the logout option is selected the action is processed in "case 3" in onNavigationDrawerItemSelected method. In this case, it is executed the showCancelDialog() that shows the DialogFragment.